# jquery not posting files to httpHandler

Tags: jquery, ajax, file-upload, ihttphandler

I've been working on file upload with jquery ajax but stuck in somewhere. Can anybody help, this is my Ajax code

```
function uploadfunction(obj) {
    var fileUpload = document.getElementById(obj.id).files;
    var files = fileUpload;
    var dataa = new FormData();
    if (files.length > 0) {
        dataa.append("ImageUp", files[0]);
    }
    $.ajax({
        url: "<%=HPath%>FileUploadHandler.ashx",
        type: "POST",
        data: dataa,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        success: function (data) { 
            alert(data);
        },
        error: function (err) {
            alert(err.statusText)
        }
    });

}
```

I've made sure that file is present in `dataa`...

Here is my event handler:

```
<asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" onchange="uploadfunction(this)"/>
```

My ashx handler

```
 public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
{
    if (context.Request.Files.Count > 0)
    {
        HttpFileCollection files = context.Request.Files;
        for (int i = 0; i < files.Count; i++)
        {
            HttpPostedFile file = files[i];
            string fname = context.Server.MapPath("~/uploads/" + file.FileName);
            file.SaveAs(fname);
        }
        context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
        context.Response.Write("File Uploaded Successfully!");
    }
    else
    {
        context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
        context.Response.Write("no file");
    }

}
```

context.Request.Files.Count always remains zero, one thing is, i am not posting form, i am getting image from onchange event of file upload button.
Please help

Comment: Please show the relevant code (click handler assignment for example) including the relevant HTML. Any console errors?

Comment: @mplungjan this is my html for that in which i've specified onchange event handler

<asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" onchange="uploadfunction(this)"/>

Comment: I have updated your question. Where is `uploadfunction` ?

Comment: i've updated my jquery ajax function. That ajax call was in uploadfunction.